# How to solve "call to undefined function ..." problem in PHP 7.4.5, XAMPP 3.2.4, Windows 10 x64?

Tags: php, function, class, undefined

I use PHP 7.4.5 and Apache 2.0 on XAMPP 3.2.4 on Windows 10 x64. PHP API version is 20190902.

I created a .php file in the 'htdocs' directory, then in that file defined a class with variables and a function, that initiates these variables, then below the class definition, I'm creating an instance of the class and call its function. Then I started Apache from the XAMPP control panel. When I open this PHP file in the browser as http://localhost/problem.php, the browser shows this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function setParams() in D:\xampp\htdocs\problem.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\problem.php on line 34
```

The function is public, so there are no problems with brackets in the class description, no scope problem, so I can't figure out where this problem comes from. Do you have any idea?

P.S. I've already restarted Apache, but the result is still the same.

Here is the code of the `problem.php`:

```
<?php

    phpinfo();

    abstract class Person {

        var $name; // = string;
    }

    class NaturalPerson extends Person {

        var $dayOfBirth; // = integer;

        var $MonthOfBirth; // = integer;

        var $YearOfBirth; // = integer;

        var $male; // = boolean;

        public function setParams ($d, $m, $y, $ml) {

            $this->dayOfBirth = $d;

            $this->MonthOfBirth = $m;

            $this->YearOfBirth = $y;

            $this->male = $ml;
        }
    }

    $np = new NaturalPerson();

    $np.setParams(1,2,1910,true);

    echo "<br>\n";

    var_dump($np);

?>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code above contains a useless `?>` at the, but lacks even the required `<?php` in the beginning. Also perhaps relevant, how are you executing that code?

Comment: 1. What this code is missing is just a <?php at the beginning.

Comment: 2. I'm running this code on a localhost using XAMPP 3.2.4 (Apache 2.0, PHP 7.4.5) in a browser by entering this URL: http://localhost/problem.php
3. Thank you very much for correcting my question. I appreciate it. English is my 2nd language.
4. As other commenters mentioned, I have to use "->" to call a member function of a class intead of ".", which is a string concatenation operator.
5. I appreciate everybody's answers! Using -> instead of . solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong in the call function. You should update:

`$np.setParams(1,2,1910,true);` -> `$np->setParams(1,2,1910,true);`

You can figure out more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_classes_objects.asp).

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem. I haven't been coding in PHP for a long time and forgot how this is done.

Comment: @BorisNY That's my pleasure to help you. Please consider accepting this as an acceptable answer if it suits you.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, to call a function of an object, use "->" and not "."

```
$np->setParams(1,2,1910,true);
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem. I haven't been coding in PHP for a long time and forgot how this is done.

Comment: @BorisNY, it is a pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you are using a string concatenation operator to call the member function on an object. What happens: PHP calls __toString() on $np (because it's an object) and append the returned value of the "setParams()" function to that of the string serialization of your object.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation! It solved the problem. I haven't been coding in PHP for a long time and forgot how this is done.